# Get members from a structured pointer Object

Tags: gcc, struct, typedef

I have the following form in c (gcc):

```
typedef struct {
  mem 1;
  mem 2;
  mem n;
} *obj;
```

How do I get a specific member from that type of structure, initialized with `obj var;`?

Comment: `1` and `2` are not valid structure member identifiers, and unless you have a definition for `mem` somewhere, it's not a valid type. Given a valid `struct` definition though, and an object of that type or a valid pointer to an object of that type, you need the `*`, `.`, and `->` operators, depending on the exact situation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, that declaration is invalid, you're trying to declare members whose identifiers are numbers. I'll assume you actually want this:

```
typedef struct foo {
    int mem_1;
    int mem_2;
    ...
} *obj;
```

You access plain struct members with a dot (`.`):

```
struct foo bar;
bar.mem_1 = 2;
```

This is perfectly fine, the compiler allocates stack space of the correct size automatically.
Now, since your `obj var` is a pointer<sup>1</sup>, we'd access its members with an arrow (`->`):

```
obj var;
var->mem_1 = 3;
```

Of course, if you're lucky, this will segfault. If not, you're likely to have a very long and enlightening session with the debugger.  Unlike declaring a `struct foo` itself, Declaring `obj var` or its equivalent `struct foo *var` does not create anything except an uninitialized pointer. You need to provide the memory for this yourself:

```
obj var = malloc(sizeof(*var));
```

Note that this merely provides the memory, its contents are still undefined, but you can safely assign to them.

<sup>1: This is the problem with `typedef`ing away pointers like you've done; it's impossible to know whether you need to use `.` or `->` without seeing the typedef or being told off by the compiler. Don't use `typedef` to hide a pointer.</sup>